# How to adjust imageview width and height correctly

Tags: android, imageview

i am trying to load/capture (load from gallery|capture from camera) an image and to upload the image back into imageview. what i want is original sized image?. for already captured images it works but when i am trying to upload image after capture there left  empty spaces before and after imageview. the empty spaces are more than image size

Help me how to fix it?

My xml Code is

```
<ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@id/UploadetAboutImageGallery">
<LinearLayout  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/UploadimageBeingTaken"
 android:background="#FF0"
 android:visibility="gone"/>
<Button 
 android:layout_width="120dp" 
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:id="@+id/UploadbtnUpload"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:text="UpLoad"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:background="#ed4022"
 android:textColor="#FFF"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:visibility="gone" />
 <Button 
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:id="@+id/UploadbtnChange"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:text="Change"
 android:background="#ed4022"
 android:textColor="#FFF"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:visibility="gone"></Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Is the ratio of the image kept correctly?

Comment: Actually i did not change image bounds these are wrap_contents in both height and width?

Comment: I'm asking because maybe you have a problem with your ScaleType of the ImageView

Comment: ivToPost.getLayoutParams().height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  ivToPost.getLayoutParams().width=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

Comment: Actually i was trying to adjust the image width fill_parent and height lets say 400dp .it was  not working than i tried wrap_contents for both width and height outcomes are odd.?